# logrotate is not executing custom shell script in postrotate

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have following logrotate configuration file

```
/home/application/*/shared/log/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 10
  missingok
  nocompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    echo "Hi....." 
    /home/application/test.sh > /home/application/test_bash.log 2>&1
    echo "By....."
  endscript
}
```

/home/application/test.sh currently content is following (I try in shell script create dummy file too, but no success)

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "=============================================="
```

When I run logrotate all files are successfully rotated but test.sh script is not executed

Logrotate potput looks following:

running postrotate script
running script with arg /home/application/*/shared/log/*.log : "
    echo "Hi....." 
    /home/application/test.sh > /home/application/test_bash.log 2>&1
    echo "By....."
"

/home/application/test_bash.log log file is not created.

I even try simple such example

```
/home/application/*/shared/log/*.log { 
  daily 
  rotate 10 
  missingok 
  nocompress 
  notifempty 
  copytruncate 
  sharedscripts 
  postrotate 
    mkdir /home/application/demo_v2/shared/log/arch 
  endscript 
}
```

Why logrotate is not executing my shell script? What I am doing incorrect?

Comment: Please show us the full output of `logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/<your_application>`?

Comment: Thanks you give me necessary hint.

I was running lograte with **d** option `logrotate -dv -f /etc/logrotate.d/<your_application>`

Without **d** all was as expected

Comment: Is /home mounted with noexec?  Is SELinux/Apparmor permitting execution of scripts in /home?  Also, your mkdir example needs mkdir -p or it will fail if the directory exists.  _Logrotate will see a fail status_

Answer (score 1):

As someone said previously the "echo" commands will fail, as logrotate has no TTY, so you might try...

```
echo "Hi....." > /home/application/test_bash.log
/home/application/test.sh >> /home/application/test_bash.log 2>&1
echo "By....." >> > /home/application/test_bash.log
```

It's unclear what logrotate might do if you attempt something like echo without a TTY.

The output from - logrotate -dvf - seems to indicate your script has run.

First try something simple like - echo foo > /home/application/test_bash.log 2>&1

If this works, then the script should be easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate does not have a magical TTY attached; where did you expect this output to be written to ?

One would normally run a script that redirects its output to a dedicate dlog, and avoid outputting anything on stdout; you seem to have confused several concepts above.

Perhaps, if we knew what it is you want to actually ***do*** with this logrotate script, somebody could help.

Comment: I even try following postrotate script. No success

`/home/application/*/shared/log/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 10
  missingok
  nocompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    mkdir /home/application/demo_v2/shared/log/arch
  endscript
}`

When I run:
logrotate -dvf /etc/logrotate.d/application_log_conf

I got Response:

`running postrotate script
running script with arg /home/application/*/shared/log/*.log : " 
    /home/application/test.sh
"`